# PySpark Column Data Turn to Row Data

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have below PySpark Dataframe:

[image]

I would like to using PySpark Datafream to convert to:

Adding one more column to indicate their date range and all city level data turn from column data to row data and adding their data range.

[image]

What is the best way achieve in PySpark?

Comment: Hi! Can you [please read](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15405732) about the problems with images of text and then edit your question to add transcriptions of your images of text as actual text? Perhaps useful: [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit

# Define the data
data = [
    ("USA", "NY", "NYC", 3, 5, 12, 16),
    ("USA", "NY", "Queen", 1, 3, 4, 12),
    ("USA", "CA", "SF", 23, 24, 11, 12)
]

# Create an initial DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["Country", "State", "City", "Order_1d", "Order_2d", "Count_1d", "Count_2d"])

# Create two separate DataFrames for 1d and 2d data
df1 = df.select("Country", "State", "City", "Order_1d", "Count_1d")
df2= df.select("Country", "State", "City", "Order_2d", "Count_2d")

# Add a 'Date_Range' column to each DataFrame
df1 = df1.withColumn("Date_Range", lit("1d"))
df2 = df2.withColumn("Date_Range", lit("2d"))

# Rename columns to match the expected output
df1 = df1.withColumnRenamed("Order_1d", "Order").withColumnRenamed("Count_1d", "Count")
df2 = df2.withColumnRenamed("Order_2d", "Order").withColumnRenamed("Count_2d", "Count")

# Combine the two DataFrames
final_df = df1.union(df2)

# Show the final DataFrame
final_df.show()
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more "df = df.withColumn("Date_Range", expr("if(Order_1d = 3, '2d', '1d')"))" is Order_1d = 3 hard coded?

Comment: Have modified the code as that hardcoded value gave incorrect result.